# How to change image from webcam width and height OpenCV Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm creating project using python and OpenCV on my RPI. Can i change camera's resolution (for best performance)? Using OpenCV in program, or in Raspbian devices options
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
[VideoCapture's set()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) function lets you do that through OpenCV. Use the propIds `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT`, and set desired values. Please note that the camera has to be capable of whatever you're setting these to.

Also, you could use [resize()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize), though it's definitely not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best option to get OpenCV working properly with the Raspberry Pi (assuming you are using the classic camera) is to use the "picamera" python module (installed by default I think).

https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/

It allows you to get raws RGB frames directly from the hardware, without using OpenCV's VideoCapture. In addition, it provides a wide range of options (brightness, FPS, white balance, etc...) to control the camera - whereas VideoCapture only let you set the size of the frames, because of incompatibilities with OpenCV and the camera's driver.